# Как запретить изменение размера панели в JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, gridpane

Вопрос в заголовке. Именно панели, а не всего окна.

Comment: я на javafx не пишу, но вы пробовали переопределить метод [`isResizable()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#isResizable--), чтоб он всегда возвращал `false` ?

Comment: А при изменении окна, что должно быть с панелью и остальными элементами?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Размер не будет превышать заданный setPrefSize-ом. Попробуй так:

```
    GridPane gridpane = new GridPane();
    gridpane.setPrefSize(100,200);
    gridpane.setMaxSize(Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE,Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
    gridpane.setMinSize(Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE, Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Смотря какая панель, например FlowPane будет иметь динамические характеристики(он переходит на новую строчку), или Group. Но есть возможность задать желаемый размер(приставка Pref), или использовать StackPane который растягивает элементы в себе на свою размер, и при этом учитывается максимальный размер элемента(их тоже можно менять).
Если вы уверены что ваша панель поддерживает то методы setSize(w, h), ну или setWidth(w), setHeight(h)

Comment: блин, неправильно прочитал